# Pandas - convert first column from row to header

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe coming from a long list of dictionaries (a sample looks like:

```
final_list = [{'name': 'total_video_followers', 'period': 'lifetime', 'values': [{'value': 10}], 'title': None, 'description': None, 'id': '5400'}, {'name': .... etc}]
```

the dataframe it creates when using

```
df_list = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
```

| Index | name | period | values | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | total_video_followers | lifetime | [{'value': 10}] | 5400 |
| 1 | total_video_followers_unique | lifetime | [{'value': 1}] | 5400 |

but I want to change the axis so the name column should be the headers, but also the id should be a header as well

| Index | total_video_followers | total_video_followers_unique | id | period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'value': 10}] | [{'value': 1}] | 5400 | lifetime |

I tried pivot and transpose but it didn't work:

```
pivoted = df_list.pivot(columns='name').reset_index()

transpose = df_list.T
```

when I try the last line, transpose, the headers are 0, 1, 2....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseder pivoting your dataframe

```
df.pivot(['id', 'period'], 'name', 'values').reset_index()
 
name    id    period total_video_followers total_video_followers_unique
0     5400  lifetime       [{'value': 10}]               [{'value': 1}]
```